# Wireshark dissector without using TCP or UDP port

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have been looking for some tutorial to write my own dissector for CPL-G3.
However, all that I found is dissectors that use TCP or UDP ports like this:

```
dissector_add (“tcp.port”, 250, myprot_handle);
```

Is there a way to use another transmission protocol, not TCP?

Comment: I think the question that needs to be answered first is: Exactly what data/network/transport protocols does CPL-G3 run over ? Is CPL-G3 somehow related to IEEE 1901 ? I note that Wireshark has dissectors for homeplug and homeplug-av which apparently run over ethernet. Are these protocols somehow related to CPL-G3 ?

Comment: he is somehaw releated to IEEE 802.15.4

Comment: Do you have a capture file containing CPL-G3 packets ? Can you share it someplace (dropbox, etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

*is there a way to use another **transmission** protocol, not TCP?*

I *think* you mean to say ***transport*** protocol, but yes, it's possible.

For example, Wireshark's [DNS dissector](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-dns.c;h=373272ea416b5ef66b14e04df259b2105fdfb739;hb=HEAD#l4029) registers with UDP, TCP and SCTP.

```
void
proto_reg_handoff_dns(void)
{
    dissector_handle_t mdns_udp_handle;
    dissector_handle_t llmnr_udp_handle;

    mdns_udp_handle  = create_dissector_handle(dissect_mdns_udp, proto_mdns);
    llmnr_udp_handle = create_dissector_handle(dissect_llmnr_udp, proto_llmnr);
    dissector_add_uint_with_preference("udp.port", UDP_PORT_MDNS, mdns_udp_handle);
    dissector_add_uint_with_preference("udp.port", UDP_PORT_LLMNR, llmnr_udp_handle);
    dissector_add_uint("sctp.port", SCTP_PORT_DNS, dns_handle);
#if 0
    dissector_add_uint("sctp.ppi",  DNS_PAYLOAD_PROTOCOL_ID, dns_handle);
#endif
    stats_tree_register("dns", "dns", "DNS", 0, dns_stats_tree_packet, dns_stats_tree_init, NULL);
    gssapi_handle  = find_dissector_add_dependency("gssapi", proto_dns);
    ntlmssp_handle = find_dissector_add_dependency("ntlmssp", proto_dns);
    ssl_dissector_add(TCP_PORT_DNS_TLS, dns_handle);
    dtls_dissector_add(UDP_PORT_DNS_DTLS, dns_handle);
    dissector_add_uint_range_with_preference("tcp.port", DEFAULT_DNS_TCP_PORT_RANGE, dns_handle);
    dissector_add_uint_range_with_preference("udp.port", DEFAULT_DNS_PORT_RANGE, dns_handle);
}
```

There are many other examples in the Wireshark source code like this.